# How to create matrix from defaultdict to implement raw bigram counts?

Tags: python, dictionary, n-gram, defaultdict

I want to implement raw bigram counts of some words. For this I created a defaultdict which contains two entity and their count like this :

```
[(('went','then'),1),(('went','forward'),3),(('go','then'),2)]
```

So to implement raw bigram counts I need to create a matrix with it which will be:

```
       then  forward 
went     1       3
go       2       0
```

How to do that? I couldn't find any way. That's a matrix., click on edit to see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *exactly* sure what you're trying to do, but the code below extracts the data from your list of nested tuples and puts it into a list of lists.

```
data = [
    (('went', 'then'), 1), 
    (('went', 'forward'), 3), 
    (('go', 'then'), 2),
]

#Gather row & column keys
rowkeys, colkeys = [list(set(u)) for u in zip(*[t[0] for t in data])]

#Put count data into 2D table
datadict = dict(data)
table = [[datadict.get((r, c), 0) for c in colkeys] for r in rowkeys]

#Dump table
print(' '.join(colkeys))
for r, row in zip(rowkeys, table):
    print(r, row)
```

**output**

```
forward then
go [0, 2]
went [3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This script solve your problem, you must create a dictionary of dictionary

```
data = [(('went', 'then'), 1), (('went', 'forward'), 3), (('go', 'then'), 2)]
res={}
for elm in data :
    dict2={}
    value= elm[1]
    key0= elm[0][0]
    key1= elm[0][1]
    dict2[key1]=value
    res[key0]=dict2

print res['go']['then']
2
print res['went']['forward']
3
```